# correct usage of pagination <a> tag

Tags: html

I am going to make a pagination. But I had a question about the Structure. In the example of the Web Standard Development Organization w3c, pagenation is implemented as follows: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_ex_pagination_active

By the way, according to w3c, The  tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from **one page to another.**

In my case, in the comments, a tag does not move to another site. Is using a tag suitable for the web standard? Should I write `ul>li`instead of `ul>li>a` ?

Comment: If it is a link to another page or the same page with different parameters then use <a>, if it is not, then use a button (ex. AJAX call and refresh of the data with JavaScript).

Comment: @AdamM. Thanks for the answer. I will connect to the same page with different parameters. Is writing a tag suitable for the web standard?

Comment: If you are going to refresh the page when it is clicked then use ul>li>a and if the button is going to change the values and update the url without reloading the page, then the best structure is ul>li>button, as it looks and feels like a button and doesn't refresh the page. That is the best standard way from the experience.

Comment: Thanks to you, I know how to organize it.